# Products Index Check on Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

First making use of PaperClip.

On the Index File i have a list of the Products in the database.

What would be the best way to check if there is a image save in the database.
Paperclips fields are standard

So i thought i would be best to do a check on the image_file_name field.

So if it is null then show one image else if not null show another icon.

Any ideas here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to Solve it

If anyone is looking for this solution.

This will check any field if it is empty then display an image/icon and display another when not

```
<%= product.image_file_name? ? image_tag('imagesuccess.png') : image_tag('noimage.png')%>
```

Hope this helps Someone